# Determine the offset and the size of another process write

Tags: linux, backup, notify, fanotify

I'm working on a backup service. It tracks changes of the files in a the directory to backup. It does that by setting a watch (using inotify with Linux) and comparing the modification time and size after a file has been changed. When it is, the whole file is copied to backup. I'm thinking, could this be done much more efficient? If the backup service can determine the offset and the number of bytes written, it can just copy that, in stead of copy the whole file. I've been looking to fanotify, which offers some interesting features, like an fd to the file modified (by the other process). Now here it stops I think. There is no way as far as I can see it how the process using fanotify can determine from the fd how the file is changed.

Do I overlook something, or is it not possible to get this information?